# creating an api in mule4, what permissions do i need in Workday to create the email for a user in Workday

Tags: dataweave, mule4, workday-api

This would be a POST call to Workday that sends the following payload:

```
{
    "email" : joe.technology@briansdistributing.com,
    "employeeId" : "111111"
}
```

I keep getting the following permissions error:

```
SoapFault{faultCode={http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.processingError, subCode=null, detail='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><detail><wd:Processing_Fault xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"><wd:Detail_Message>The task submitted is not authorized.</wd:Detail_Message></wd:Processing_Fault></detail>', reason='Processing error occurred. The task submitted is not authorized.', node='null', role='null'}
```

This is the transform message to request the call to Workday:

```
output application/xml
ns ns0 urn:com.workday/bsvc
---
{
    ns0#Change_Work_Contact_Information_Request: {
        ns0#Change_Work_Contact_Information_Data: {
            ns0#Person_Reference: {
                ns0#ID @(ns0#"type": "Employee_ID"): payload.employeeId
            },
            ns0#Person_Contact_Information_Data: {
                ns0#Person_Email_Information_Data: {
                    ns0#Email_Information_Data: {
                        ns0#Email_Data: {
                            ns0#Email_Address: payload.email,
                            ns0#Email_Comment: p('workday.createEmailMessage') as String default ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems an authorization error. Also if you are doing an HTTP request share the HTTP Requester operation.

Comment: thank @aled, that last article worked.